# Convert from base to derived class at runtime using template logic

Tags: c++, oop, c++14, c++17

I am writing a small Database of sorts and seem to have run into an issue. I have 3 `Statement` types (each of which correspond to `CREATE`, `INSERT` and `SELECT`. The definitions of these types are:

```
class Statement { }; // Base class, contains common stuff like the table name

class CreateStatement : public Statement {
  /* Contains information regarding the CREATE statement after parsing (name and datatype of
  each column) */
}

class InsertStatement : public Statement {
  /* Contains information regarding the INSERT statement (list of values to enter inside the DB) */
}

class SelectStatement : public Statement {
  /* Contains information regarding the SELECT statement ( list of attributes to select from the DB) */
}
```

My parser has functions to appropriately parse these 3 types of input statements, but I return the base class from each of these functions. An example is:

```
Statement parse_create(const std::string& stmt) {
  CreateStatement response;
  // Parse stmt
  return response;
}
```

My rationale behind doing this was to avoid if/else cases in my main REPL loop (instead of checking whether input is of type create and then conditionally returning `CreateStatement` or some other derived class, just call `parse` once and that would return a `Statement` object). The issue I am running into is that of executing upon this returned `Statement`. I have 3 different functions to execute these commands (`execute_create`, `execute_insert` and `execute_select`) and these take the derived classes as parameters respectively (`CreateStatement`, `InsertStatement` and `SelectStatement`). This is so that the execute functions can make use of information that was stored in the derived class objects while parsing.

Could I use some sort of template logic to call the appropriate execute function, or have I lost the information from the derived class once I returned the base class after parsing? I tried doing some stuff like:

```
Statement parsed_stmt = parse(input); // input is the string the user entered
if (std::is_same_v<decltype(input), CreateStatement>) {
  execute_create(parsed_stmt);
}
```

but this obviously won't work due to the type being explicitly `Statement`.

I would also appreciate any feedback on the design. Thanks!

Comment: When you return by value you [*slice*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the objects. Polymorphism only works with references or pointers. That of course assumes your class-hierarchy is polymorphic to begin with. If it's not, then pointers or references to a base-class won't work without a lot of up- and down-casting.

Comment: The go-to tool for this sort of thing is a virtual function, not a template. Did you try that yet?

Comment: You can't return by value the base type, it will slice your object and remove any derived functionality. Welcome to C++, where features fight each other due to bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would do this would be something like this:

```
class Statement {
    ...
    virtual void parse(const std::string &stmt) = 0; // A string view will work here too.
    virtual bool execute() = 0;
    ...
};

class Create : public Statement {
    ...
    virtual void parse(const std::string &stmt); // Implement
    virtual bool execute(); // Implement
    ...
};

... // more statements
```

and then implement these appropriately in the derived classes. You could have parse non-virtual and call a virtual `create` method, but that seems redundant to me. Note creation returns nothing - it simply changes the state of the object (stores the statement or whatever).

Similarly, `execute` is stored in the derived class, so it knows how to execute itself - even if you have a reference to a `Statement` object, the correct derived method will be called without extra effort. I assumed a boolean is returned to indicate success.

This means you need to work with references (or pointers) to statements. This is the main strength of inheritance with polymorphism - being able to operate the same way on differently derived objects without worrying about what they are exactly.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated. This solved my problem. On to doing more projects and learning the language!

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic dispatch:

```
struct Base {
  abstract virtual void method() = 0;
  virtual ~Base() = default;
};

struct Derived: Base {
  void method() override {}
};
```

Static dispatch (CRTP), usually an overkill:

```
template <class D> struct Base {
  void method() {
    static_cast<D*>(this)->method();
  }
};

struct Derived: Base<Derived> {
  void method() { ... }
};
```